# Why does the command \MRhref in the AMSRefs package take two arguments?

Tags: macros, amsrefs

Apologies in advance if this is a naive question. I am trying to understand how the `\MR` command works in the [AMSRefs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsrefs) package. Going through the amsrefs.sty style file, I see that the relevant portions appear to be lines 2673–2689 and 2933–2951, as follows:

```
\def\strip@MRprefix#1#2#3#4\@nil{%
    \def\@tempa{#1#2#3#4}%
    \if#1M%
        \if#2R%
            \def\@tempa{#3#4}%
        \fi
    \fi
}
\def\MR#1{%
    \relax\ifhmode\unskip\spacefactor3000 \space\fi
    \begingroup
        \strip@MRprefix#1\@nil
        \edef\@tempa{MR\@nx\MRhref{\@tempa}{\@tempa}}%
    \@xp\endgroup
    \@tempa
}
\providecommand{\MRhref}[2]{#1}

\IfOption{msc-links}{%
    \@ifundefined{href}{}{%
        \def\parse@MR#1 (#2)#3\@nil{%
            \def\MR@url{http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=#1}%
            \def\@tempd{#1}%
            \def\@tempe{#2}%
        }%
        \def\MRhref#1#2{%
            \begingroup
                \parse@MR#1 ()\@empty\@nil%
                \href{\MR@url}{\@tempd\vphantom{()}}%
                \ifx\@tempe\@empty
                \else
                    \ \href{\MR@url}{(\@tempe)}%
                \fi
            \endgroup
        }%
    }{}
}{}
```

The [documented source](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/amsrefs/amsrefs.pdf) says on page 111 regarding the latter portion that:

> Unless you’re using pdfTeX, links cannot be broken across lines, which causes problems for long-form MR numbers such as “MR2149145 (2006d:01012)”. To mitigate the problem, we manually break such numbers into two separate links.

Okay, so I *think* I follow what's going on here, even if I don't understand the intricacies of all the macros like `\@nx` etc. But what's stumping me is the definition of `\MRhref`. I notice that we have `\providecommand{\MRhref}[2]{#1}`. So, `\MRhref` takes two inputs and only sees the first? Why take the second input at all, then? Besides, in the definition of `\MR` it looks like `\MRhref` takes the same input both times, anyway. Also, in the definition of `\MRhref` under the `\IfOption{msc-links}` part, I don't see where the second argument is used.

Could someone please explain to me what is going on here with the `\MRhref` command?

Comment: I'm not sure about it. When `\MR` is called it issues `\MRhref{\@tempa}{\@tempa}` (where both instances of `\@tempa` are fully expanded), so the two arguments are always equal. Possibly something that remained from some previous version where the two arguments were actually needed to comply with different situations.

Comment: @egreg Thank you for taking a look. My original intent was to define a command along similar lines named `\Zbl` for zbMATH Open reviews, but I got stumped at the definition of `\MRHref`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you link to says

> For older versions of some AMS document classes, this patch is needed.
>
> ```
> 2659   \providecommand{\MRhref}[2]{#1}
> ```

Which implies some pre-historic version of the AMS classes used a two argument version of this command, so that is kept but the second argument is not used (and it is arbitrarily passed the same argument twice in the call you showed).